# xslt - infer result from children

Tags: xml, xslt

Given the following xml input:

```
<Sections>
 <Section number="1">       
  <Step number="1">
   <SubStep number="1" Pass="True">             
    <SubSubStep number="1" Pass="True"/>                    
    <SubSubStep number="2" Pass="True"/>                    
   </SubStep>
  </Step>
  <Step number="2">
   <SubStep number="1" Pass="False">                
    <SubSubStep number="1" Pass="True"/>                    
    <SubSubStep number="2" Pass="False"/>                   
   </SubStep>
  </Step>
 </Section>
</Sections>
```

How can I transform it to:

```
<Sections Pass="False">
 <Section number="1" Pass="False">      
  <Step number="1" Pass="True">
   <SubStep number="1" Pass="True">             
    <SubSubStep number="1" Pass="True"/>                    
    <SubSubStep number="2" Pass="True"/>                    
   </SubStep>
  </Step>
  <Step number="2" Pass="False">
   <SubStep number="1" Pass="False">                
    <SubSubStep number="1" Pass="True"/>                    
    <SubSubStep number="2" Pass="False"/>                   
   </SubStep>
  </Step>
 </Section>
</Sections>
```

I want to infer the result of the parent from the children. If any of the children have a Pass="False" result the parent result will be Pass="False". Backwards recursion?

Comment: XSLT is not very good at transforming whitespace, it works better on XML. :)

Comment: No transform is needed. :) I think you need to edit this to include your XML and desired output.

Comment: haha... after struggling trying to add a code block I finally gave in and decided to read the guidelines :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

1. Use the [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) to copy everything from the input to the output, and
2. for element nodes without a `Pass` attribute, add it. Set it to `False` if there is at least one `Pass` attribute with value `False` in the children, and to `True` otherwise.

---

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <!-- identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- set missing Pass attribute -->
  <xsl:template match="*[not(@Pass)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="Pass">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test=".//*[@Pass = 'False']">False</xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>True</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "`.//node()[ @Pass='True' ]`" XPath expression to see if any children of the current node are "True".